# Can i reference the selector of a delegated element using this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:

```
$('#enquiry-form').on('click','.close', function(){ 
    $(this)..code..
});
```

`$(this)` would reference `'.close'` but is there a way to reference `$('#enquiry-form')` in a similar fashion to using javascript's `this` or `$(this)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event.delegateTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) to get the delegated target.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9GU8/)**

```
$('#enquiry-form').on('click','.close', function(event){ 
     alert($(event.delegateTarget)[0].id);
});
```

> This property is most often useful in delegated events attached by
>   .delegate() or .on(), where the event handler is attached at an
>   ancestor of the element being processed. It can be used, for example,
>   to identify and remove event handlers at the delegation point, [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, not parent() like the other answers! thanks Adil.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can refer it by using `$(this).parent().` ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple parent dom with same selector(say classname `enquiry-form`), You can use `.closest()` along with `this`:

```
$(this).closest('.enquiry-form');//would be $(this).closest('#enquiry-form') in your case
```

But as ids are unique,You can simply use:

```
$('#enquiry-form')
```

Comment: its an id. Then why did you specify closest?

Comment: @Preprocezzor:In case of multiple same ids, closest is required

Comment: @MilindAnantwar The problem with closest() is, that it searches through DOM and gets the first matched element. siblings() or next() is more effective, if he has multiple IDs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**parents**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [**closest**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
 $(this).parents('#enquiry-form')
```

**or**

```
 $(this).closest('#enquiry-form')
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you have to call your code in this way:

```
$('#enquiry-form').on('click','.close', function(){ 
    $(this).parent().code..
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xegW5/2/)